# FBML based app suddenly stopped working since Nov.18,2011

Tags: fbml, platform

My FBML based app suddenly stopped working since Nov.18.2011. It was working fine before that. And nothing has changed from our side. Could that be some of the new changes Facebookk put in on Nov.18 ( http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/600/ ). Does anyone else has the similar problem? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using Firebug, when I try to the run the app, I got this error: uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for <http://apps.facebook.com> to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger Is there any settings in the Dev-app that might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

My FBML app stopped working around this day too.  The problem is that they switched to the new auth system, where instead of sending the fb_sig HTTP parameters to identify the user and verify that the request came from Facebook, they now send one single parameter called signed_request.  Which language/library are you using to interface with Facebook?  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ for more details on this new signed_request parameter.